# Choice the right source during mapping with mapstruct

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

I want to start a discussion with all of you on the best way to approach on this problem.
I have a java object like this, it's a source

```
public class Source{
  private String customValue;
  private List<String> listOfCustomValues;
  
  //etc
}
```

and, of course, i have a target java object

```
public class Target{
  private String ownCustomValue;
        
  //etc
}
```

now, i would to mapping in this way (or something similar)

```
@Mapper
public abstract class MapperSourceToTarget {
  @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
  @Mapping(target = "ownCustomValue", qualifiedByName = "customMapping")
  public abstract Target fromSourceToTarget ( Source source);

@Named("customMapping")
public String toFuelType(Source source) {
  String firstValue = source.getListOfCustomValues().get(0);
  return ( firstValue.isEmpty() || firstValue == null ) ? source.getCustomValue() : firstValue;
  }

}
```

do you have any suggestion or criticism on this behavior? I can do this in a better way?

Answer (score 1):

When the target mapping needs to be derived of multiple properties, or from a list then the approach in the question is the best way.

```
@Mapper
public abstract class MapperSourceToTarget {

    @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
    @Mapping(target = "ownCustomValue", qualifiedByName = "customMapping")
    public abstract Target fromSourceToTarget ( Source source);

    @Named("customMapping")
    public String toFuelType(Source source) {
        String firstValue = source.getListOfCustomValues().get(0);
        return ( firstValue.isEmpty() || firstValue == null ) ? source.getCustomValue() : firstValue;
  }
}
```

Doing it like this allows you full control of the way you want to map your property